Should I avoid using StatefullWidget throught my flutter app?
I'm developing a taxi-hailing app and currently implementing Bloc for state management. While I've aimed to utilize stateless widgets where possible, I've found that for disposing controllers and building UIs more efficiently, a stateful widget seems necessary. However, I've encountered performance issues with the StatefulWidget. Should I persist with its usage, or do you have any alternative recommendations for maintaining performance while still leveraging the benefits of state management with Bloc?
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const HomePage({super.key});

 @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
 }

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Position? _currentPosition;
  Set<Marker> markers = {};
  String _placeNameFromCurrentPosition = "";
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentPostion();
    
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    mapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            // polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(_currentPosition?.latitude ?? 9.005401,
                  _currentPosition?.longitude ?? 38.763611),
              zoom: 14.46,
            ),
            onTap: (argument) {},
            onLongPress: (argument) {},
            markers: {
              Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId('marker_2'),
                position: LatLng(_currentPosition?.latitude ?? 9.005401,
                    _currentPosition?.longitude ?? 38.763611),
                infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: 'Marker Title 2',
                  snippet: 'Marker Snippet 2',
                ),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                    BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue), // Custom marker icon
              ),
            },
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          ),
          CustomBottomSheetModal(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  AppNavigator.push(Routes.destinationSelection, {
                    "position": _currentPosition,
                    "address": _placeNameFromCurrentPosition
                  });
                  // sl<SocketManager>().goLive();
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppTheme.lightGray,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.r)),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.r),
                      child: const Text("Where to?")),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.h,
              )
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentPostion() async {
    try {
      _currentPosition = await LocationService().determineCurrentPosition();
      await getPlaceNameFromCurrentPosition();
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
      LogUtils.logExceptions(e, stackTrace: stackTrace);
    }
  }

  Future<void> getPlaceNameFromCurrentPosition() async {
    if (_currentPosition != null) {
      _placeNameFromCurrentPosition = await LocationService()
          .getAddressFromCoordinates(
              _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude);
    }

  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
   }

How could I improve this code performance? Any suggestion is appreciated.

It's ok to use stateful classes, whenever you use elements that needs to be disposed. But make sure call the build() method by calling setState only when It is needed to. And I see you're using LocationService().method() like this. which creates different instances in memory every time you call any of its method, affecting performance. You can use singleton class to fix this.
